Best practice for managing requirements.txt in develop/main branches?
Our product uses a requirements.txt file to specify required third-party packages.
In the development code branch, our practice is to not use any pinned versions in this file, so that we always get the latest updates and discover version upgrade conflicts as soon as possible.
So in develop, the file might look like this:
package1
package2
package3

But in the main branch, we do pin everything to specific versions, to ensure a stable release product.
So in main, the file might look like this:
package1==3.2
package2==5.77
package3==1.6

This works well for us, except that when we merge from develop to main, we get merge conflicts on that one file, because it is legitimately different between the two branches.
So far we've just been manually resolving the conflicts.  But is there a better solution?

At what point are the versions pinned during the release process? So long as whatever commit pins the versions finds its way back into the histories of both main and develop, you won't have any merge conflicts. For example, in a git-flow like workflow, you could 1) make a release branch off develop, 2) create a commit that pins the version, 3) merge the release branch into both main and develop, 4) create a commit in develop that un-pins the versions.

A similar problem is often encountered when incrementing a project's version number between develop and release versions. Workflows that help solve that problem may be helpful here

This sounds like a prime candidate to check in as a temporary commit that you keep on your develop  branch until you want to merge it into main. Then you create a tag or branch to keep a reference to the temporary commit, do an interactive rebase to remove it from the branch, (run git test on all commits,) merge the branch, and then bring back the temporary commit with cherry-pick or rebase.
